# How to represent a time that does not change - Python

Tags: python-3.x, time

I went to set the time to 9:00pm in my game, and choose when to change it, adding minutes instantly, not a gradual change. It does not need to state whether it is pm or am. What `Type` would best represent this static time that I can change? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the `datetime` type from the builtin `datetime` module.  If you don't want the date portion, you can get just the time portion, e.g. `mydatetime.time()`. To add an amount of time to your variable, use `timedelta`, as in:

```
mydatetime += timedelta( minutes=3.5 )
```

Edit: type changed from `time` because `time` [does not support arithmetic](http://bugs.python.org/issue1487389).

Comment: Thanks. It seems a bit like the time type changes over time, from the documentation. I will have to test it. If it does, I guess I will use a decimal, and change its output to a time format manually.

Comment: I don't know why you think the value of a data item of type `time` will change without your program altering it.  It won't.

Comment: Okay thanks. The documentation didn't really touch on if it is a time that keeps on ticking.